# How variable hoisting happens inside function

Tags: javascript, hoisting

how it can happen as variable a is declared after console.log, its value should be undefined

```
function x(){
    b();
    function b(){
      console.log(a)   //displays value of a 
    }
    var a = "hello world"
}
x()
```

Comment: b is never called and the main function is apparently never executed, hence it should print nothing at all.

Comment: Its not meant to be executed im just trying to understand, see the updated answer

Comment: I have updated the answer, is it makes sense?

Comment: It logs `undefined` for me. Cannot reproduce. Try the code again. You might have defined `a` earlier while testing.

Comment: @blackHawk: With your update it does log `undefined` now as expected. Only the declaration is hoisted, not the initialisation (assignment).

Answer (score 0):

This is known as variable hoisting in Javascript. You can read more to it [here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting). Basically, the JavaScript interpreter "looks ahead" to find all the variable declarations and "hoists" them to the top of the function. in layman terms for ease you can relate this behaviour as the interpreter scans twice the code, whilst first scan, it hoists the variables.

```js
function x() {
  function b() {
    console.log('a: ', a); //displays value of a
  }
  var a = "hello world";
  b();
}
x();
```

But this will be undefined if its a self invoking. check this:

```js
function x() {
      (function b() {
        console.log('a: ', a); //displays value of a
      })()
      var a = "hello world";
    }
    x();
```

As its self invoking, while the first scan only, its executed and it looks for `a` and logs `undefined`.

Things remains the same for even:

```js
function x() {
  b();
  function b() {
    console.log('a: ', a); //displays value of a
  }
  var a = "hello world";
}
x();
```

Comment: @blackhawk I have tried explaining the answer, let me know if you have further concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code:

```
function x(){
    b();
    function b(){
      console.log(a)   //displays value of a 
    }
    var a = "hello world"
}
x()
```

executes as if you'd written this:

```
function x(){
    var a;
    function b(){
      console.log(a)   //displays value of a 
    }
    b();
    a = "hello world";
}
x();
```

So at the time `b()` is called, the variable `a` *exists* (otherwise you would get an undefined reference error which would stop execution instead of just logging `undefined`), but it has not yet been assigned a value.

Does it make more sense now?